# How to replace the data of a specific key inside a JSON in BigQuery?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have the JSON data in the below format and I want to replace the values of **_nanoseconds** with some dummy value ('111') without disturbing the JSON structure.

```
{
  "Category": "Winning",
  "CreatedAt": {
    "_seconds": 1602574892,
    "_nanoseconds": 461491000
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "_seconds": 1602574892,
    "_nanoseconds": 463021000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *,
  regexp_replace(json, r'("_nanoseconds": )(\d+)',  '\\1777') as dummy_json
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer and it's working perfectly fine with the integer values. But, I have some of them in the string format as mentioned below. Can you please help me with that as well?

 `{
  "Category": "Winning",
  "CreatedAt": {
    "_seconds": 1602574892,
    "_nanoseconds": "2401:4900:52f0:304a:34cd:93e6:ea31:3cce"
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "_seconds": 1602574892,
    "_nanoseconds":"2401:4900:52f0:304a:34cd:93e6:ea31:3cce"
  }
}`

TIA. Also, please share the reference links :)

Comment: I got the answer by using `([":0-9a-zA-Z ]+)` at the place of `(\d+)`